What song does “Due” by Mindless Self Indulgence sample (if any)?
The ‘da da da da da’ part has a very familiar melody, but i can’t seem to figure out what it’s reminding me of.

Hi Moon, can you please link to the part you are referring to in a music video?

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nIjj-1ArGLA it’s the 1st vocals that you hear in the song
